# Visual Studio Code unable to read file

Tags: linux-mint, visual-studio-code

So this just happened out of nowhere, I'm currently working on Linux Mint OS where I have my remote project open from File Manager and I open the directory with code, put VS code suddenly can't open up any of the files in the directory.

```
[2022-02-07 14:31:46.792] [renderer1] [error] Error: Unable to read file '/run/user/1000/gvfs/ftp:host=HERE_IS_IP_OF_MY_REMOTE/watchdogbot/index.php' (Unknown (FileSystemError): An unknown error occurred. Please consult the log for more details.)
```

The full error I get in the logs is following:

```
at Object.error (vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:578:42065)
    at Object.onError (vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:67:28451)
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:67:27546
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:67:25727
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at I.emitError (vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:67:25716)
    at I.error (vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:67:25377)
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:574:12003
    at o.fire (vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:67:1712)
    at K (vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:83:3429)
    at D.onResponse (vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:83:4402)
    at D.onBuffer (vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:83:4242)
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:83:1817
    at o.fire (vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:67:1712)
    at EventEmitter.G (vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:65:50696)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Object.onMessage (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:105:1177)
```

Now I already tried to reinstall the VS code for my system, but nothing changed, it still can't open up **ANY** of the files. I tried googling this issue and all I found out was that something might be wrong with pathing but reinstalling should generally fix the issue, did not though...

Comment: Post your launch.json

Comment: There is no such thing, and vscode is unable to create one
`Unable to create 'launch.json' file inside the '.vscode' folder (Unable to write file)`

Comment: That would explain the error. You don’t have write permissions. Resolve that issue and your unknown error likely will be resolved